# How to get href with Watir using Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, watir

I'm trying to use Watir to grab a specific link on a page:

[Screenshot: Here is the href I am trying to grab.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u929y.png)

My guess is I need to specify the ancestor element `biz-website`(?) then traverse down to the `a` tag and grab its `href` somehow, but I'm not sure what the syntax of my code would need to be do that.

Any ideas or tips?

Comment: Your question is premature. You need to try, then when you have a problem ask a specific question about that problem. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". As is, we have no idea what you tried so any detailed answer would be a tutorial. “[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)” is related also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to get the value of the `href` with

`browser.span(:class, 'biz-website').a.href`

If the class `'biz-website'` is not unique for spans on your page, you can also use `'biz-website js-add-url-tagging'`. If that is still not unique, you could also try

`browser.span(:text, 'Business website').parent.a.href`

Comment: Glad to assist!